# Update a property from a callback

Tags: vuejs2

I am trying to use a function from a library that is called like this

`convertString(input, options, callback)`

Having a simple template like the following

```
<template>
 <textarea v-model="inputText"></textarea>
 {{ convertedText() }}
</template>
```

I tried the following

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      inputText: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    convertTextCallback: function (err, result) {
      if (!err) return result
    },
    convertedText: function () {
      options = ''
      convertString(this.inputText, options, this.convertTextCallback)
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that the `convertedText` function needs to return a string but the string is generated when the callback runs. How can I return the string generated from the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use async/await however using asynchronous calls in this way is discouraged. I recommend using a watcher and another data property.

First of all, I believe that the setup you provided would not do what you want it to even if it was not asynchronous. It will call converted text on page load when input text is empty and this will then not update as it is not a computed property.

A working example:

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      inputText: '',
      result: '',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    convertTextCallback: function (err, result) {
      if (!err) this.result = result
    },
  },
  watch: {
    inputText: function() {
      options = ''
      convertString(this.inputText, options, this.convertTextCallback)
    }
  }
}
```

And then in your template

```
<template>
 <textarea v-model="inputText"></textarea>
 {{ result }}
</template>
```